# Javascript - Quicksort algorithm visualiser animation problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

So I am creating a Quicksort Algorithm Visualiser and I have been stuck for the last couple of days on why values are not being pushed to my animations array. Currently it is returning as an empty array when I test the code. I need the values that are being compared and also when they are swapped to be animated and thus be pushed into the animations array. This is my first time asking a question here so I hope I've made sense. I am new to JavaScript so I'm anticipating that I'm making a silly mistake. Here is the code I am working on:

```
export function getQuickSortAnimations(array) {
  const animations = [];
  if (array.length <= 1) return array;
  quickSortHelper(array, 0, array.length-1, animations);
  return animations;
  
}

function quickSortHelper(
  array,
  startIdx,
  endIdx,
  animations,
  ) {
      if (startIdx < endIdx) return;
      let pIndex = partition(array, startIdx, endIdx, animations);
      quickSortHelper(array, startIdx, pIndex-1, animations);
      quickSortHelper(array, pIndex+1, endIdx, animations);
      return animations;
      }

function partition(
  array,
  startIdx,
  endIdx,
  animations,
  ) {
      let pivot = array[endIdx];
      let pIndex = array[startIdx];
      for (let i = startIdx; i < endIdx; i++) {
          if (array[i] < pivot) {
              animations.push([i, pIndex]);
              swap(array, i, pIndex);
              animations.push([i, pIndex]);
              pIndex++;
          }
      }
      swap(array,pivot,endIdx);
      return pIndex;
  }



function swap(
  array,
  a,
  b,
  ) {
    let temp = array[a];
    array[a]=array[b];
    array[b]=temp;
}
```

Comment: You can write JS as a "[stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/15472)", and that will make it easier to test by others, because they will not need to copy&paste it into a browser shell to test it.

Comment: Your `startIdx` is always smaller than the `endIdx` when you first call `quiskSortHelper` (with values `0` and `array.length -1`), so you never sort anything.

Comment: You should start by writing a correct `QuickSort` before you try to animate it. There are several other problems in your code - animation is the least of your troubles. There are many, many online examples you can learn from. For an example, you have `pIndex = array[startIdx]`; so if my array is `[100, 200]` you will later try to access `array[100]`, and happily continue to process the value `undefined`...

Comment: @tucuxi Thanks for the response. I have rewritten my whole algorithm thanks to your advice. I would appropriately give you recognition in the form of a tick or upvote, whichever is used here, if I knew how to.